# Generate Unique next value in ID based on multiple columns unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three columns below:

```
ID | Tag_name | View_name
--------------------------
12 | 23_GB_23 | screen1
13 | 23_GB_24 | screen2
```

How to generate Unique next value in ID based on Tag_name and View_name columns,
Tag_name, View_name should be unique.

I was thinking on  NOT NULL IDENTITY or using sequence_name.nextval and how to make sure only Tag_name, View_name unique values will be inserted, put Primary keys on this columns? is there any efficient way to manage this case?

thanks,
S

Answer (score 2):

you can use composite primary key on these columns
Primary key (Tag_name, View_name)

```
Alter table table_name 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (Tag_name, View_name)
```

now only unique value will be inserted and this columns wont accept null.
If you want the column to accept null then you can use UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS